# Javascript/jQuery - Display inches in feet and inches

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math

I'm making a BMI calculator (see JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/b5ww2/) and I want the height in inches to display in feet and inches. I also want the weight in pounds to be displayed in stones and pounds.

This is the code I'm using to convert the slider value to cm and inches:

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
  $( "#heightslidecm" ).html( ui.value + 'cm' );
  $( "#heightslidein" ).html( (ui.value*0.393700787).toFixed(0) + 'in' );
}
```

My js knowledge isn't great - especially when it comes to the math aspect.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Great plugin! Would I be allowed to use this on my site? I'd like to style it with https://github.com/simeydotme/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips

Comment: Feel free! It's nice that something I wrote will be used elsewhere :)

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to share with you what I have rewritten based on what you had :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You simply need to include the logic for the conversion. Here is an example for feet and inches:

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#heightslidecm" ).html( ui.value + 'cm' );

    var inches = (ui.value*0.393700787).toFixed(0);
    var feet = Math.floor(inches / 12);
    inches %= 12;

    $( "#heightslidein" ).html( feet + "ft " + inches + 'in');
}
```

You just need to repeat this same logic for the pounds/stone using the appropriate conversion values.

Comment: is the inches not: inches = inches - (feet * 12)

Comment: @eskimo - Do you know what the `%` does?

Comment: It previously said: inches = inches / 12; not modulus

Comment: apologies, my eyes letting me down... it didnt, it was mod :)

Comment: Actually, I'm having trouble doing the same thing but to change the pounds into stones and pounds. So far I've done this:
`slide: function( event, ui ) {
  $( "#weightslidekg" ).html( ui.value + 'kg' );
  var pounds = (ui.value*2.20462).toFixed(0),
  stones = Math.floor(pounds / 14);
  pounds = %= 14;
  $( "#weightslidelb" ).html( stones + "st" + pounds + "lb" );
}` but it's just breaking the sliders to the point where they're not appearing at all

Comment: You are probably missing a parenthesis somewhere. If your code is a bit of a mess take a moment and realign it. The error should appear. Or, try using a better IDE that highlights your braces for you.

Comment: I'm using Komodo IDE and it's not throwing any errors. I used the exact same syntax as I did for the feet and inches which works great but nothing I try is working

Comment: Use firebug when you launch the page. Your IDE won't pick up on runtime JS errors. Firebug will help you with that.

Answer (score 5):

OK — after googling and landing here I tried the above.
Even though the post is related to converting Centimeters (CM) to inches, it comes up in Google for ANY conversion (and Inches to Feet and Inches in my case).

For my project I was trying to convert INCHES to Feet and Inches (and yet here I am). To save anyone else who encounters the INCHES to Feet and Inches question one extra uGoogle-eh here is how I would do that in Javascript:

```
                let height = 75; // this could be any number of inches
                let feet = Math.floor(height / 12);
                let inches = (height - (feet * 12));
```

The above should let you convert from Inches to feet and inches (if Google un-knowingly landed you here like it did for me).
Good luck out there!

Answer (score 2):

Here's my answer. I converted following excel formulae to JavaScript.

```
=INT(B5/12)&"ft.  "&ROUND(MOD(B5,12),1)&"in."
```

```js
function toFeetandInch(inches){
    return (parseInt(inches/12) + ' ' + Math.round(inches%12,1)+"'")
}

console.log(toFeetandInch(69))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will show the value in feet + inches.

```
<script>
  function rangeSliderFeet(value) {
      var feet = value / 12;
      var inches = value % 12;
      document.getElementById("rangeFeetValue").innerHTML = Math.floor(feet) + "\'" + inches + "\"";
    }
</script>
```