# Convert Height(Centimeter) to Feet'inches using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi Everyone I am Calculating BMI using height and weight it's working fine but I want to convert entered height(centimeter) in Feet'inches

**HTML**

```html
//height in Centimeter
<input type="number" onblur="myFunction()" min="0" name="height" id=height_' + len + ' class="txtInput2 personalize-form box-width" required/>

 //Weight
<input type="number" onblur="myFunction()" min="0" name="weight" id=weight_' + len + ' class="txtInput4 personalize-form box-width" required/>
```

**Javascript**

```
function myFunction(){
  var height = document.getElementById("height_1").value;
  var weight = document.getElementById("weight_1").value;

  if(weight > 0 && height > 0){ 
   var finalBmi = weight/(height/100*height/100)
     document.bmiForm.bmi.value = finalBmi
   if(finalBmi < 18.5){
    var health= document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "UW"
   }

   if(finalBmi > 18.5 && finalBmi < 25){
       var health1= document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "IW"
       alert(health1);
     }
   if(finalBmi > 25){
     var health2= document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "OW"
      alert(health2);
    }
  }
else{
  //alert("Please Fill in everything correctly")
 } 
}
```

Comment: And 12 inches in a foot, should be trivial math? Write it down on paper first, then write the JS code to do the same math

Comment: It has been already discussed in stack .please refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541392/convert-centimeters-to-inches)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
function toFeet(n) {
      var realFeet = ((n*0.393700) / 12);
      var feet = Math.floor(realFeet);
      var inches = Math.round((realFeet - feet) * 12);
      return feet + "&prime;" + inches + '&Prime;';
    }
```

Comment: You can refer the duplicated question. This answer doesn't add any value.

Comment: @RazvanDumitru previous QUESTION doesnt  have acceptable answer!!!

Comment: This one does -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723585/javascript-jquery-display-inches-in-feet-and-inches

Comment: @RazvanDumitru Dont down vote if the answer isnt wrong.

Comment: @DušanTichý I am getting height in height variable now i want to Use your function how can i use..please suggest

Comment: @websmentor.com

I suppose: 

var heightInFeets =  toFeet(height);

Comment: @DušanTichý thank you

Comment: This doesn't work for the values 12"0' check @adeneo Comment that works

Comment: export function cmtoFeetInches(cm: any) {
    let realFeet = ((cm * 0.393700) / 12);
    let feet = Math.floor(realFeet);
    let inches = Math.round((realFeet - feet) * 12);

    if (inches === 12) {
        inches = 0;
        feet = feet + 1;
    }
    return `${feet === 0 && inches === 0 ? `0 in` : `${feet === 0 ? `${inches} in` : `${inches === 0 ? `${feet} ft` : `${feet} ft ${inches} in`}`} `}`;
}

Comment: The above function doesn't work for 182cm, it shows 5' 12" instead of 6' 0". I submitted an edit, but here it is anyway: `function toFeet( cm ) {
          var totalInches = (cm * 0.393700);
          var inches = Math.round(totalInches % 12);
          var feet = Math.floor(totalInches / 12);
          if (inches === 12) {
              feet += 1;
              inches = 0;
          }
          return feet + '\'' + inches + '\"';
        }`

Comment: Yes, It's working. Thank You